# Vue.js - calling data() inside mounted() throws error

Tags: vue.js

```
mounted () {
  this.data(); // or only data();
}
```

message: "this.data is not a function"

What is the best way to call data() after page load?

Comment: Are you trying to access the local properties of your component that were declared in `data()`? Or do you actually have a method defined named `data()`?

Comment: Why you trying to call `data()` in `mounted()` data is returning object containing all your declared reactive variables

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i don't know this.data() function,
but just use data like sample below:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'bar',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.foo) // will print "bar"
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are correct. In vue this will refer to the VueComponent instance and you access fields in data directly. Also accessing data with this.data() would not make sense as data will be called to create your "data" so there will be no function left to invoke in the component